# Use ESLint with Airbnb style and tab (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

I'm working on a React.js application and I'm trying to lint my code. I use ESLint with the Airbnb style, but I have these errors:

```
../src/Test.jsx
  4:2   error  Unexpected tab character                                no-tabs
  5:2   error  Unexpected tab character                                no-tabs
  5:3   error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  react/jsx-indent
  6:2   error  Unexpected tab character                                no-tabs
```

Here my code:

**Test.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';

function Test() {
    return (
        <h1>Test</h1>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

**.eslintrc:**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "indent": [2, "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1, "VariableDeclarator": 1 }],
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-indent-props": [2, "tab"],
  }
}
```

As you can see above, I would like to indent with tab.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
loaders: [{
  test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/,
  loaders: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"],
  exclude: /node_modules/
},
...
]
```

I also tried to indent why 2 spaces, without success. I really don't understand why I have theses errors. Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: @azium I'm using Sublime, but I have also tried to create again my file with vim.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @mark-willian told me, I added some lines in my **.eslintrc** and it works:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "rules": {
        "indent": [2, "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1, "VariableDeclarator": 1 }],
        "no-tabs": 0,
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "react/jsx-indent": [2, "tab"],
        "react/jsx-indent-props": [2, "tab"],
    }
}
```

Thank you for all of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The airbnb rules want you to use spaces instead of tabs for formatting your code. Good editors (sublime is one!) will let you use tabs but translate them to spaces when saving your code.

You need to change the config of your sublime; go to *Preferences*-*Settings* and customize the following settings:

```
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

Sublime will convert your existing code - click on the text in the status bar at the bottom right that says tabs or spaces.

You can selectively turn off eslint rules if (for example) one of airbnb's rules doesn't match your coding style guide.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't want to use spaces.

Comment: OK, then you'll need to disable the eslint no-tabs and also the react/jsx-indent rules.

Answer (score -1):

Try replace [every tab to spaces](http://tabstospaces.com/).

It is also a good idea to enable the [ESLint autofix](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#fix) feature with [this `eslint-loader` option](https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader#fix-default-false) in your webpack configuration.

Comment: With spaces, I obtain this error:
   4:3  error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 2 spaces  indent

Comment: You can find a simplified version of my code there: GitHub [edited]

Answer (score -2):

You can add this comment on page which you get no-tabs error.

```js
/* eslint-disable */
```